# Does the Referrer-Policy header affect Google Analytics tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, http-headers, referrer

I'd like to use the `Referrer-Policy` header in my site.

Depending on [which value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#directives) I use, it will send more, less or no referrer information to a link's target site.

If I use a restrictive value, e.g. `origin`, could it impact my Google Analytics tracking?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091760), but I'm unsure whether that's a definitive answer.